# What percentage of tweets do I get from a free twitter API?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am streaming certain keywords from Twitter API and I wanted to understand what percentage of the total tweets do I get from using the streaming function in Tweepy? (I am using the free developer account - Is there any benefit in terms of volume if I upgrade to a pro account?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Approximately 500,000,000 tweets occur every day. The software you refer to limits you to collect only 500,000 requests per month where each request can contain 120 tweets.